# Routing a folder and it's contents instead of single files

Tags: playframework

Public folder:

[image]

Routes:

```
# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                         controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/html", file="index.html")

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET /*file/                        controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/", file)
```

I am looking for a way to pass the entire public folder and it's contents, ideally on first page load. The way `GET /*file/                        controllers.Assets.at(path = "/public/", file)` works seems to only allow me to grab a single file at a time. i.e `localhost:9000/javascripts/script.js` I'd like all my public content on the front-end so I can do my front-end work without making a bunch of separate calls.

The biggest problem so far is the js and css don't come along to the front end on the routing of the index.html

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to bundle all your `js` files into a single fat file and all your css files into a fat css file and use them in `<script>` and `<style>` tags in `index.html`.

You can use a build tool like `webpack` to minify and bundle them, tools like `webpack` also takes care of hashing the files so that if any of the file's content changes, the name of the bundle will change, but for this, you need to follow a different mechanism to refer that generated file in your index.html.